# Adding items to cart ionic framework

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having trouble adding products (playlists) to the cart. I am not able to understand the reason behind this. I am new to ionic framework and angular js.
Can anyone please help me out with this.

THis is my code for cart.html

```
 <ion-view view-title="Cart">
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>


  <ion-item item-width = "50%" ng-repeat="product in cart track by $index"  >
  <p class='product-title'>Item: {{product.title}}  </p>  
  <p class='product-price'>Price:{{product.price}}</p> 
  <p class='product-amount'><input type = "number" min = "0" placeholder = "0" value = "0" ng-model = "amount"></p>
  <span class = 'product-total'>{{product.price*amount}}  </span>



   </ion-item>


</ion-list>
   <button class = "button button-small" ng-click = "payment()" >Proceed to  Payment </button> 
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

THis is my code for playlists.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Playlists">
  <ion-content>
 <ion-list>


 <ion-item item-width = "50%" ng-repeat="playlist in playlists track by $index" > 
 <div class = "row">
  <div class = "col">Item: {{playlist.title}}</div>
 <div class = "col">Price:{{playlist.price}}</di            </div>    
<ion-option-button class = "button-positive" ng-click =    "addtocart(playlist)" >Add to Cart</ion-option-button> 
 <ion-option-button class = "button-assertive" ng-click =  "removefromcart(playlist)" >Remove from Cart </ion-option-button> 

     </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

THis is my code for  controllers.js

```
 .controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.playlists = [
{ title: 'Reggae', price: '10' , id: 1 },
{ title: 'Chill', price: '10', id: 2 },
{ title: 'Dubstep', price: '10', id: 3 },
{ title: 'Indie', price: '10', id: 4 },
{ title: 'Rap', price: '10', id: 5 },
{ title: 'Cowbell', price: '10' , id: 6 }
];

   $scope.cart = [];
  $scope.addtocart = function(playlist){


  var productInCart = false;
  $scope.cart.forEach(function(prod, index, prods){
    if (prod.id === playlist.id) {
      productInCart = prod;
      return;
    }
  });

  if (productInCart) {
    //do nothing
  } else {
    $scope.cart.push(playlist);
  }
};


 $scope.removefromcart = function(playlist){

$scope.cart.forEach(function(prod, i, prods){
    if (playlist.id === prod.id) {
      $scope.cart.splice(i, 1);

    }
  });

 };
```

Comment: is playlist and cart seperate state..?how u are handling route..?just try.. declaring $rootScope.cart = [];

Comment: When I posted this question, yes they were two separate states. But because this wasn't working I moved all the cart.html code to playlists.html    making necessary changes (items and cart in one page) and removed the cart state. This worked. Can we have two templateUrl's in one state?